# Coupled System of Differential Equations.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider the coupled ODE system

$$
[D^2c_1]x(t)+[D^2c_2+Dc_3]y(t)=0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$

$$
[D^2c_4-Dc_5]x(t)+[D^2c_6+Dc_7+c_8]y(t)=0~~~(2)
$$

with initial and terminal values $x(0)=q,x(h)=q',y(0)=p ,y(h)=p'$, and where the $Dx=\frac{d}{dt}x$ and $D^2x=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x$ stand for first and second differential operators.\

Could anyone help me solve these equations ive been trying for hours and hours? Note $c_i,i=1,\dots,8$ are all constants.

Comment: Laplace transform?

Comment: You can obviously integrate the first equation once directly as it is. Then insert the expression you find for $Dx$ into the second equation to get an equation completely in $y$. Then you get a second order linear DE with right side and constant coefficients. There exists a solution machine for that, if you call it Laplace or characteristic polynomial makes no difference in the necessary computation.